# Disable remote validations on client_side_validations gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I'm quite pleased with the gem features. However, the current implementation of server-side validations uses [synchronous ajax](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/226). Thus, I would like to know if these could be disabled application-wide, so I don't have exclude individual validators everywhere in my views, and also to be able to enable them later in case the implementation changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it can easily be achieved with something like this:

```
// seems that the name will change in a future release
var validator = clientSideValidations || ClientSideValidations;
// remove all remote handlers
if (validator) validator.validators.remote = {};
```

It should be run after `rails.validations.js` has been executed. If you are concerned in polluting the global namespace, just enclose it in a `(function() { ... })()` call.

Comment: $('form').disableClientSideValidations() works as well